# Transaction unconfirmed for hours

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I need any help you can provide me regarding the transaction `ea36f903db582e5b87c3618208cae2b28957521b8567f5d7934fc8b47a663bd8`

It has been unconfirmed for more than 6 hours and I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: The transaction is confirmed by now.

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction can be seen here: https://blockchain.info/tx/ea36f903db582e5b87c3618208cae2b28957521b8567f5d7934fc8b47a663bd8

One of the inputs is address [1BPAcceeSNiNEHeeR1wEQDspvcq17jM142](https://blockchain.info/address/1BPAcceeSNiNEHeeR1wEQDspvcq17jM142). It has an additional unconfirmed transaction at [671454f599c947cc01bf69defe68a6e59e869352006fb8b86df17dd51bc1d1fd](https://blockchain.info/tx/671454f599c947cc01bf69defe68a6e59e869352006fb8b86df17dd51bc1d1fd). One of *that* transaction's inputs is [1KhqWzuRSB4cLsAnTtKjf8TGtY7HsNAdM4](https://blockchain.info/address/1KhqWzuRSB4cLsAnTtKjf8TGtY7HsNAdM4), which has an additional unconfirmed transaction at [8b780e2d3197ebdaf74688333fefc0fa83a11ff24f687423899354455881c14c](https://blockchain.info/tx/8b780e2d3197ebdaf74688333fefc0fa83a11ff24f687423899354455881c14c). And here is the problem:

[image]

Your later transactions cannot complete until their inputs are confirmed. Your only option is to wait at this point.